# Split my maven pom into different files

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I do not want to change my project/module structure. Its just my pom file is getting large and complex (due to lots of dependencies) and want to separate it into easily navigable sub files ... is this easy ?

I am looking for something similar to the import resource available for spring context definition files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a couple of options for breaking up your pom files:

- Create a parent pom to move things like the plugins, pluginManagment and dependencyManagement sections into. This separates these sections out from the files where you are actually defining what dependencies a module will use. You can find some good examples [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance).
- Use dependency management imports to modularise your dependencyManagment section, you can see an example [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Importing+Managed+Dependencies). This allows you to do things like separate the dependency management of third party dependencies from your own projects dependencies.

Comment: solution one works if you have modules, but, if is only one project with no modules, this does not work, same for solution #2